# Automatically load From adress on mail, when "Answer customer" button is pressed

Tags: email, case, email2case, servicecloud, case-object

I have multiple mail-adresses which leads to the same queue in Service Cloud. When I answer the customer, by pressing the Feed View button "Answer Customer" I can load a specific template through apex code, but is it possible to autoselect a specific "from address"?
I want to load the same e-mail adress as the one which the "customer" originally wrote when reaching out for support, so the customer doesn't get confused when receiving answer from different email-adress.
I know that I can specify which email-adresses which should be in the picklist to choose from. But I want to auto-select the appropiate one based on a field which exists on the case (origin-email-adress).

How is this possible?